# CSS label :before and :after

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am learning CSS and I am having a bit of trouble recognizing properties and understanding some of the syntax. in the CSS below.

```
.tabs nav li.tab-current:before,
.tabs nav li.tab-current:after {

}
```

I understand that tabs is a class and the `nav li` with the class `tab-current` within the `tabs` class in html will be applied with the same CSS.

Example:

```
        <div class="tabs">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="tab-current">Hey</li>
                    <li>hello</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

However I'm not quite sure what `:before` and `:after` represent. Could someone provide me with an example? Thank you

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They set something after and before the element you are selecting. For example:

```
p:after {
    content: 'hi! im after';
}

p:before {
    content: 'hi! im before';
}
```

You will understand it better if you see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWcw9/).

Answer (score 5):

`:before` and `:after` create pseudo elements as 'children' for the element they are applied to. They are often used for certain stylings, or error messages.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XjUM8/1/

```
div:before {
    content: "Before";
    background: red;
}

div:after {
    content: "After";
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

You can also set them up to show up on hover

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XjUM8/2/

```
div:hover:before {
    content: "Before";
    background: red;
}

div:hover:after {
    content: "After";
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Also, take a look at MDN :
[Before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) & [After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Answer (score 3):

`:before` and `:after` are CSS Selectors that allow you to add content before or after the element in question.  An example is of adding an arrow after a link to show progress:

HTML

```
<div class="testAfter"><a>Arrow After this link</a></div>
<div class="testBefore"><a>Arrow Before this link</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.testAfter:after{
    content:"\25B6"
}
.testBefore:before{
    content:"\25C0"
}
```

Fiddle to show:
http://jsfiddle.net/yPkVL/1/

You can add all kinds of things; images, text, etc. You can style them and add different positionings.  You can do all kinds of things.  It's like adding an extra div before or after the div in question without having to change the HTML markup.

Reference:

[Before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp)

[After](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp)

Answer (score 3):

`:after` and `:before` are called pseudo-elements. They're used to inject some content to your DOM through the CSS.

For instance, say you want to add an icon after every link that targets external websites (we'll assume that these links href all begin with "http://"). This would be a real pain in the neck to try and append this manually. Using the CSS pseudo-element `:after`, you can simply do something like this :

```
a[href^="http://"]:after {
  content:url('href.png');
}
```

and bam ! You're good to go.

`:after` and `:before` allow you to simply inject some text or image, but they can also be used [in many creative ways](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/).

**Beware though**, they can be applied to anything except "replaced elements" : this means that you won't be able to use those pseudo-elements on tags such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<object>`, `<img>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [W3School explains it pretty well](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp), did you read that up and not understand something?

Essentially what it means is you're going to insert whatever is in the :before area before what content is already in there, and the :after after the content.

:before and :after are selectors, they're used to select what you want to style.

The [example on w3schools is as follows](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
      p::before
      {
        content:"Read this -";
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>My name is Donald</p>
    <p>I live in Ducksburg</p>

    <p><b>Note:</b> For ::before to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

What this does is print out:
`Read this - My name is Donald` and `Read this - I live in Duksburg`

After will esentially do the same thing.

There are